# How to push app to cloudfoundry from Java programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, maven, cloud-foundry

I would like to upload an app (jar) which is on my `classpath` (maven dependency). I use the following code:

ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

```
    URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();
    File msjar = null;
    for(URL url: urls){
        if ( url.getFile().contains("gs-spring-boot")) {
            try {
                msjar = new File(url.toURI());
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(url.getFile());
    }
    try {
        client.uploadApplication("hello-app-wishbox", msjar );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.generateMultipartBoundary()[B

    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.generateMultipartBoundary(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:364)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeMultipart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:300)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:233)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:801)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:594)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.LoggingRestTemplate.doExecute(LoggingRestTemplate.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:503)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientImpl.uploadApplication(CloudControllerClientImpl.java:1393)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientImpl.uploadApplication(CloudControllerClientImpl.java:1359)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.CloudFoundryClient.uploadApplication(CloudFoundryClient.java:276)
    at hu.fnf.devel.test.TestSteps.when(TestSteps.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

I assume that I do not use the method correctly. Can anybody send me an example usage for uploadApplication?

Comment: It happened that on my `classpath` there were 2 versions of spring core. This caused this error. I don't know if I should close this question or answer it? Although now I get `org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.CloudFoundryException: 400 Bad Request
 (Request invalid due to parse error: lexical error: malformed number, a digit is required after the minus sign.
                                       --Dm9aPvklggtdtqwCyavRrBugH80L7
                     (right here) ------^`

Comment: I would delete this question and start a new one with your new problem.